# Not able to close ShakeService.java once started

Tags: java, android

When switch is on then ShakeService.java starts and detects shaking of phone but when switch turned off then how can i kill that activity or stops that detection?

MainActivity.java

```
if (OnOffSwitch.isChecked()) {

                    //start shake detection
                    Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, ShakeService.class);
                    //Start Service
                    startService(intent);

                    OnOffSwitch.setText("Service is On");
                    Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Service starts", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                } else {
                    OnOffSwitch.setText("Service is Off");
                    Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Service stopped", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
```

ShakeService.java

```
package com.example.android.safetyapp;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.app.Notification;
import android.app.NotificationManager;
import android.app.PendingIntent;
import android.app.Service;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.graphics.Color;
import android.hardware.Sensor;
import android.hardware.SensorEvent;
import android.hardware.SensorEventListener;
import android.hardware.SensorManager;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.os.Handler;
import android.os.IBinder;
import android.support.v4.app.NotificationCompat;
import android.util.Log;
import android.widget.Toast;

import java.util.Random;

public class ShakeService extends Service implements SensorEventListener {

    private SensorManager mSensorManager;
    private Sensor mAccelerometer;
    private float mAccel; // acceleration apart from gravity
    private float mAccelCurrent; // current acceleration including gravity
    private float mAccelLast; // last acceleration including gravity

    @Override
    public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {
        mSensorManager = (SensorManager) getSystemService(Context.SENSOR_SERVICE);
        mAccelerometer = mSensorManager
                .getDefaultSensor(Sensor.TYPE_ACCELEROMETER);
        mSensorManager.registerListener(this, mAccelerometer,
                SensorManager.SENSOR_DELAY_UI, new Handler());
        return START_STICKY;
    }

    @Override
    public void onAccuracyChanged(Sensor sensor, int accuracy) {
    }

    @Override
    public void onSensorChanged(SensorEvent event) {
        float x = event.values[0];
        float y = event.values[1];
        float z = event.values[2];
        mAccelLast = mAccelCurrent;
        mAccelCurrent = (float) Math.sqrt((double) (x * x + y * y + z * z));
        float delta = mAccelCurrent - mAccelLast;
        mAccel = mAccel * 0.9f + delta;
        // perform low-cut filter
        if (mAccel > 36) {
            Toast.makeText(ShakeService.this, "Shaking detected", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            mAccel = 0;
        }
    }
}
```

I tried by declaring static variable in ShakeService.java and then kill it by using finish command in MainActivity but it doesn't work for me so please guide me to do this.

Comment: Have you tried calling stopServioce?  of course you need to override onStop in your service to unregister from sensor events.

Comment: Thank you Gabe. Now its working fine.